# How to force graphics card fans to rotate at certain RPM?

Tags: nouveau

My [MSI NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/gtx-970-gaming-4g.html)([GM204 GPU](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/nvidia-gm204.g767)) graphics card using `nouveau` driver starts to display artifacts seen below after every few weeks:
[image]
[image]

I'm forced to reboot the workstation because `Xorg` reboot or `nouveau` diver unloading and then loading does not help. `Xorg` is started with `-logverbose 6`, but nothing useful has been logged. I also loaded the `nouveau` driver with the `debug` parameter- maybe this reveals something useful next time the issue reoccurs. However, I have noticed that the fans of the graphics card never spin after the POST. In other words, when I turn on the workstation([Supermicro X9DR3-F](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1259.pdf) motherboard), then the fans spin for a while, but around the time when the UEFI Option ROMs are loaded, the fans stop spinning. Could it be that those artifacts seen on the images above are caused by GPU overheating? `lm-sensors` `sensors-detect` does not detect my graphics card temperature sensors and I don't have an infrared thermometer, but both the heat-pipes and the radiator of the graphics card are really hot. I tried to find a way to [force the fans to spin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nouveau#Fan_control), but looks like my card does not support this:

```
$ sudo find /sys -name pwm1_enable -o -name pwm1
$
```

Graphics card BIOS is not modified and I have tried with `nouveau` driver versions `4.4.0-171` and `5.4.0-26`. At least so far according to `dmesg -T | grep nouveau` the `nouveau`(started with `debug` parameter) has logged nothing about fan control.

Am I correct, that the `nouveau` driver does not support the manual fan control for my graphics card? Is it possible to force a certain fan speed by modifying the graphics card BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://us.msi.com/Graphics-card/support/GTX-970-GAMING-4G#down-utility shows MSI has a Windows utility for fan control, but nothing for Linux. So, it can be done, but MSI doesn't make it easy. The chances of that utility working under WINE are slim.

If no code is found to do that, you could disconnect the fans from the card, and wire them to an unused fan connections (from FAN1..6, FAN A, or FAN B) on the motherboard (locations A-H in the photo below), pages 1-5 and 2-28 of your [motherboard manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1259.pdf).

[image: Fan headers on motherboard from motherboard manual]

Yes, it's Rube Goldbergian, but far quicker and far more certain than trying to hack the BIOS.